# Can't run individual tests within Intellij gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

I am attempting to create a project with Gradle, when I run individual tests I get this error.

> Information:26/10/16 11:22 - Compilation completed with 1 error and 0
>   warnings in 158ms Error:gradle-resources-test:Sunday-Sessions_test:
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.gradle.api.specs.AndSpec.getSpecsArray()[Lorg/gradle/api/specs/Spec;

I have tried refreshing the gradle project and have also done file->invalidate caches and restart, this has not helped. Here is my gradle file, can anyone see why this is happening?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.ratpack:ratpack-gradle:1.3.3"
        classpath "com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:1.2.3"
    }
}

ext {
    // The drivers we want to use
    drivers = ["chrome", "phantomJs"]

    ext {
        gebVersion = '0.13.1'
        seleniumVersion = '2.52.0'
        chromeDriverVersion = '2.19'
        phantomJsVersion = '1.9.7'
    }
}

apply plugin: "io.ratpack.ratpack-groovy"
apply plugin: "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow"
apply plugin: "idea"
apply plugin: "eclipse"

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    // Default SLF4J binding.  Note that this is a blocking implementation.
    // See here for a non blocking appender http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/async.html
    runtime 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.12'

    // If using Spock, need to depend on geb-spock
    testCompile("org.gebish:geb-spock:$gebVersion") {
        exclude group: 'org.codehaus.groovy'
    }
    testCompile("org.spockframework:spock-core:1.0-groovy-2.4") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
    }

    // If using JUnit, need to depend on geb-junit (3 or 4)
    testCompile("org.gebish:geb-junit4:$gebVersion") {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
    }

    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java
    compile group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '2.52.0'
    compile "org.shamdata:sham:0.3"

    // Drivers
    testCompile "org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-chrome-driver:$seleniumVersion"
    // using a custom version of phantomjs driver for now as the original one does not support WebDriver > 2.43.1
    testCompile("com.codeborne:phantomjsdriver:1.2.1") {
        // phantomjs driver pulls in a different selenium version
        transitive = false
    }

    testCompile('io.ratpack:ratpack-remote-test:1.3.0') {
        exclude group: "org.codehaus.groovy"
    }
    // http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice
    compile group: 'com.google.inject', name: 'guice', version: '3.0'

    compile 'io.ratpack:ratpack-handlebars:1.2.0'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-parent:2.7-1'
    compile 'postgresql:postgresql:9.1-901-1.jdbc4'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.4.4'

    testCompile ratpack.dependency('test')
    compile ratpack.dependency("remote")
    testCompile ratpack.dependency("remote-test")
    compile ratpack.dependency("hikari")

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.restfb/restfb
    compile group: 'com.restfb', name: 'restfb', version: '1.26.0'
    //Grab the user location with GeoIP2
    compile 'com.maxmind.geoip2:geoip2:2.8.0-rc1'

}
```

Comment: If you run all tests do they run?
Can you run individual tests via command line?

If they previously worked and you have just upgraded could this be the same issue?
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207212509-Intellij-Idea-2016-2-gradle

Comment: If I do ./gradlew check it works fine, i'll check the link out, thank you